# Position: fixed; is breaking site

Tags: html, css

Why does adding `position: fixed;` break the nav bar? I've tried looking around and can't find answers elsewhere.

CSS:

```css
.nav-top{
    font-family: 'Cherry Cream Soda', cursive;
    font-size: 25px;
    background: #171717;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    padding: .4em .3em;
    display: flex;
}

.centered{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!-- Top Bar -->
<nav>
    <div class="nav-top">
        <img src="images/logo.png">
        <div class="centered">
            <h2>Memories</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- End Top Bar -->
```

[cite with fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5tLQ.png)

[cite without fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFgHD.png)

Comment: Please could you make your code into a runnable snippet within the question as when I copy and run it, with the absolute changed to fixed and with a dummy img, the problem is not reproduced, everything looks fine. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example